# Append Counter for uploadfiles C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asyncfileupload

I need to append counter number to files while saving the uploaded files, for example client upload 2 files imagex.jpg, imagey.jpg

I want to save them to server as Client_UPI_1.jpg, Client_UPI_2.jpg

Below is the code i am using

```
public class CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
{
    string _filename = null;
    public CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(string path,string filename) : base(path) { _filename = filename; }

    public override Stream GetStream(HttpContent parent, HttpContentHeaders headers)
    {
        Logger.LogMessage(LogType.Debug, "GetStream Start");
        var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", ""));
        Logger.LogMessage(LogType.Debug, "GetStream complete");
        return base.GetStream(parent, headers);
    }

    public override string GetLocalFileName(HttpContentHeaders headers)
    {
        ContentDispositionHeaderValue disposition = headers.ContentDisposition;
        string filename = (disposition != null && disposition.FileName != null) ? disposition.FileName : String.Empty;
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(filename.Replace("\"", ""));
        return String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", (_filename));
    }

  }
```

Prepare CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider in which our multipart form data will be loaded

```
string fileUploadPath = Path.Combine(ConfigHelper.FILE_UPLOAD_LOCATION);
int counter = 0;
string filename = "Client_UPI_" + counter + ".jpg"; // NEED TO UPDATE THE COUNTER SO THAT FILE NAME A SEQUENCE NUMBER
CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(fileUploadPath,filename);

var task = request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).
    ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(o =>
    {
         //some logic
    }
);
return task;
```

Currently all my filenames save as "Client_UPI_0.jpg", I want to update the counter number based on the sequence of the files, like file1 will be "Client_UPI_1.jpg" and file2 will be "Client_UPI_2.jpg" so on

Comment: What is your question? What's wrong with the code you have? Any errors? Where?

Comment: As @Symon pointed out, you need to provide more details to your post so others can understand better and provide you with solutions.

Comment: Added more details thanks